# C# : How do i post a form to a website with some checked checkboxes?

Tags: c#, forms, post, web, checkbox

I'm working in C#, and I want to POST to a website that has multiple checkboxes and returns a datafile depending on which checkboxes are checked.

First of all, how do I post a form with checked checkboxes ?
And once that is done, how do I get the datafile the site sends me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this simple ASP code, we can see how checkboxes values are sent through a POST request:

#### tst.asp

```
<%
Dim chks
chks = Request.Form("chks")
%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="someForm" action="" method="POST">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk01" name="chks" value="v1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk02" name="chks" value="v2" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk03" name="chks" value="v3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
    <h3>Last "chks" = <%= chks %></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The *H3* line show us this, if we check all the checkboxes:

```
Last "chks" = v1, v2, v3
```

Now we know how the data should be posted. With the sample code below, you should be able to do it.

#### C# method sample

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System;

...

void DoIt()
{
    String querystring = "chks=v1, v2, v3";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(querystring);

    WebRequest webrequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://someUrl/tst.asp");
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    webrequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    using (Stream data = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        data.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            /* post ok */
        }
    }
}
```

Hope I've helped.

Useful links:

- Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
- Example: http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx
- Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not completely clear.
Suppose the webpage I want to post to has in the html-source
< input type='checkbox' value='0' name='thing1' checked='checked' / >
< input type='checkbox' value='0' name='thing2' checked='checked' / >
< input type='checkbox' value='0' name='thing3' checked='checked' / >

How do I post to it setting checks for thing1 abnd thing2 ?

Comment: You would post "thing1=0&thing2=0". If it's checked, the "name=value" pair is sent. If you have several checkboxes with the same name, the values are sent in the same "name", separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make some WebRequests using the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` namespace.

You can create a **GET** *or* a **POST** connection with HttpWebRequest.

There's a great article on it [here](http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx) and you can also check out [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest` on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

Comment: But how do I check checkboxes ?

Comment: You'll want to look into the `postdata` you send with the request. So you'd POST to `process_page.php` with the information `check=1&check2=1&check3=1`, etc.